# Code not working while trying to pull user login data from form in php

Tags: php, database, forms, validation

I created a registration form that works fine in php for a project I am undertaking. I attempt to use another form, a login form  in which to pull the username and password data from the user to verify it against the database. However I am getting parsing errors and other errors. I haven't started validation yet as I haven't got the basics in this ready.

I don't think I'm going about this the right way or if it's just a silly mistake.

```
    <EDIT Remove Important Info>


  // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {  
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }


     if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])){ //already logged in   
     //$url= 'X'; // any page
        exit(); //ends script if user already logged in

     } else { //not logged in or submitted

        }


       $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
       $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
    $notify="";
    if(isset($_POST['notify_box'])){ $notify = $_POST['notify_box'];




    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `websiteusers` WHERE username ='$user_name' AND password ='$pass'");

     $count = $mysqli_num_rows($query); //checks db
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

     if($count==0){ //db empty
      echo "Sorry, password and username not in db. Click here to try again.";

    }

    else{ // pw and un match, user login success
    $_SESSION['logged']=1; //start session
    $_Session['username']=$user_name; //session data
    }
    // } // opening brace for this was not found
    mysqli_close($con);
    exit();
    } // opening brace for this was not found 


?>
```

---

- [**And here is a jsFiddle of my HTML form**](http://jsfiddle.net/aisinikins/L8LUh/)

Comment: "However I am getting parsing errors and other errors."  ... but you're not going to share them with us?

Comment: I think the syntax highlighting of stackoverflow may be highlighting your problem.

Comment: Hi @DigitalChris , I get the following error > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/danu_fa1/public_html/login.php on line 25

Comment: Also another error which said that the mysqli_close at line 30 was unexpected.

Comment: Is there more to this script? The last 10 lines or so just set some variables and then promptly forget them because the script ends?

Comment: This (for one thing) `$username=form($_POST['user_name']);` is invalid. Use `$username=$_POST['user_name'];` unless you have a function called `form()` @Aisinikins

Comment: @DigitalChris Yes, I have some basic validation, I'll edit the post to add it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi , I changed that and I am now getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/danu_fa1/public_html/login.php on line 31. Would you have any idea why that error is occurring?

Comment: So, I take it that you "DO" have a function named `form()` then. @Aisinikins

Comment: Probably because of the missing quote in `WHERE username ='$user_name` change it to `WHERE username ='$user_name'` and it "should" work. @Aisinikins

Comment: I'm also putting an answer together for you, based on my comments, which am hoping is now working for you. @Aisinikins

Comment: @Fred-ii- I created a form in the html page (posted above under code) , does that mean i use form($_POST['x'] or $_POST['x'] ?

Comment: Use `$_POST['x']` and not `form($_POST['x']` because using `form()` would be taken as a `function()` in turn cause an error. But I have something ready for you to look at that I can post below. @Aisinikins

Comment: Yet, I noticed are two extra `}` braces at the end of your code. @Aisinikins that will cause an error also. Also unsure about `$url= 'http://danu6.it.nuigalway.ie/sm4business/browse.html';` where is `$url` being defined? I don't see it anywhere else in your code.

Comment: You also had a missing semi-colon at the end of your `$query...` see what I posted below. Theoretically, it should work. Let me know. @Aisinikins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

I found this in your form

```
<input name="user_name" type="varchar" >
```

which should be

```
<input name="user_name" type="text">
```

Also, use this

```
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
```

instead of

```
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
```

yet I'm unsure about the password line, since you were using `md5` and now just plain text.

You may have to set it back to:

```
$pass=md5($_POST['pass']);
```

---

There are a few issues with your code.

You have a missing quote at the end of `'$user_name`

```
WHERE username ='$user_name
```

Which needs to be changed to:

```
WHERE username ='$user_name'
```

as well as a missing semi-colon at the end of your query. `$query=mysqli_query("SELECT....`

And this (for one thing) `$username=form($_POST['user_name']);` is invalid, since `form` would be considered a function.

Use `$username=$_POST['user_name'];` or better yet:

```
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_name']);
```

A missing semi-colon at the end of `$password=md5($_POST['pass'])`

A missing `$con` at the beginning of the query.

Which is included in the complete rewrite below.

**Line rewrite:**

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `websiteusers` WHERE username ='$user_name' AND password ='$pass'" );
```

Plus, I noticed you're storing passwords using `md5`. It's no longer recommended to use this. Do look into using [`PHP's password function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

**Complete rewrite:**

**N.B.:** The `$url` variable has not been defined anywhere else, so I'm unsure of its functionality. Plus there were two unused ending braces `}` at the end of your code, so I commented those out, along with the `exit();`

You may also be closing your DB connection prematurely with the placement of `mysqli_close($con);` should you be faced with another error message. I left it in place, but commented out and then moved at the end of the script.

Please give this a try, hoping things will fall into place as they should.

```
<?php
    // Create connection
     $con=mysqli_connect("X","X","X","X");
     session_start(); //starts  users session

     // Check connection
    if (!$con) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

     //echo "1 record added";

     if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])){ //already logged in   
     $url= 'http://danu6.it.nuigalway.ie/sm4business/browse.html'; // any page
        exit(); //ends script if user already logged in

     } else { //not logged in or submitted

        $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_name']);
        $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);

     } // mysqli_close($con); // may be being closed prematurely.

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `websiteusers` WHERE username ='$user_name' AND password ='$pass'");

     $r = $mysqli_num_rows($query); //checks db
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

     if($r==0){ //db empty
      echo "Sorry, password and username not in db. Click here to try again.";

    }

    else{ // pw and un match, user login success
    $_SESSION['logged']=1; //start session
    $_Session['username']=$user_name; //session data
    }
    // } // opening brace for this was not found
    // exit();
    // } // opening brace for this was not found

    mysqli_close($con); // moved here

 ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your help Fred I have fixed the errors mentioned above and I have removed the url  for now to see if it was causing the error. However it still seems to be the query, i got this error again.> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/danu_fa1/public_html/login.php on line 26

Comment: You're welcome. Did you use my code above, or did you modify yours? You did have a missing `;` semi-colon at the end of your `$query...` @Aisinikins I did edit it a minute ago.

Comment: Wait, I know. It's the missing semi-colon at the end of `$password=md5($_POST['pass'])` my bad, I didn't catch that earlier. @Aisinikins will edit my answer. Which was also in your code. **Edited comment:** Answer has been edited to reflect the changes. Please reload.

Comment: Hi Fred, I caught that myself a few minutes ago. I also removed the check connection query because I got an error telling me it was an empty query. Another error has come up about a variable I think I incorrectly named so I'm going to try and sort that and hopefully it will finally work.

Comment: Hi. I think you need to add a `$con` in `$query=mysqli_query("SELECT` try `$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT...` @Aisinikins I edited my answer just now to reflect the change, please reload. Most probably/likely the reason.

Comment: How are you making out since my last edit? @Aisinikins

Comment: Hi, I added $con into the query and fixed a couple of errors I made with the spelling of the  variables. It seemed to be going ok but Im getting notices now > Notice: Undefined index: username in /home/danu_fa1/public_html/login.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: password in /home/danu_fa1/public_html/login.php on line 21

Comment: Also I posted the current code to the original post

Comment: I found this in your form `<input name="user_name" type="varchar" >` which should be `<input name="user_name" type="text" >` @Aisinikins try it with that now, that should fix it. Try that. Am looking to see about the password thing. Ok, use this `$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);` instead of `$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);`

Comment: You're using this `$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);` yet your input is named `pass` @Aisinikins You were using `md5` but am unsure how your using the password method.

Comment: I think you may need to revert to using `$pass=md5($_POST['pass']);` if your passwords are already stored as `md5`. @Aisinikins

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks for catching that i was using password instead of pass as my input. I accidentally switched those and did the same thing with the username variable. I caught the varchar mistake a few minutes ago so this has sorted it. I only started PHP this week and I made lots of silly mistakes that I should have caught no matter the language, lol. Anyhow, there are no errors now! I still have work to do to get it exactly how I want it but as of now its at a great point. Thanks so much for all of your efforts tonight.

Comment: Hi, and you're welcome. Am glad to have been able to help out and am sure you'll further enjoying programming in PHP. Yet, do try and use something other than `md5` for password storage. The link I included in my answer is a good start, plus you could also look into another method for password storage called `crypt()`. Here is the link >>> http://php.net/crypt Cheers! @Aisinikins

Comment: Hi, Yes I have removed md5 for the moment and looking into better password storage is on top of my to-do list.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check connection 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())   { 
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();   
 }
```

make it this as

```
 //Check connection 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {   echo "Failed to
connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();   }
```

Comment: Hi, that was actually just a copy paste error to this site on my part so it isn't whats affecting my code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing errors are typically a simple mistype. If you put a ; in the wrong place, or don't put it at all... etc.

Try using the edits made by Grant Palin in your code, and see if this fixes your issue.